# DbContext ExecuteSQLCommand with no parameters

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to pass in a SQL string to delete some records. I'm using the DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand function, however in addition to the SQL string it expects a parameter list of the form: params Object[] parameters

Since I don't need to send any parameters I tried passing null instead but this generates an error saying null is not a valid parameter. I can't find an overload of the method. How do you send a SQL command requiring no additional parameters?  Here's an example of my code:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM SignoffCommentAttachment 
WHERE SignoffCommentAttachment.SignoffCommentID 
IN (SELECT [SignoffCommentID] FROM [SignoffComments] 
WHERE SignoffID = " + signOffID.ToString() + ")", null);
```

Comment: have you looked at the `MDSN` Explanation of DBContext.Execute Command 
`public int ExecuteSqlCommand(
 string sql,
 params Object[] parameters
)` this is the method signature .. it expects param as `Array` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Looks like a good case for [Sql Injection Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in it's current form.

Comment: Not sure how it could be attacked since the method that contains this code only accepts an int as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get a little SQL Injection Protection, you SHOULD use parameters here. You have one parameter. You should probably also be using a stored procedure, but that's another question.

I would code it like this...

```
var parms = new ParameterCollection();

parms.Add("signOffId", signOffID);

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM SignoffCommentAttachment 
WHERE SignoffCommentAttachment.SignoffCommentID 
IN (SELECT [SignoffCommentID] FROM [SignoffComments] 
WHERE SignoffID = @signOffID)", parms);
```

I didn't check my syntax there but that's the method I would use. Only I would use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 7):

The parameters is a params parameter, so you can pass 0 to many objects for it.  This should work

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM SignoffCommentAttachment WHERE SignoffCommentAttachment.SignoffCommentID IN (SELECT [SignoffCommentID] FROM [SignoffComments] WHERE SignoffID = " + signOffID.ToString() + ")");
```

You should really parameterize signOffID though.  Something like

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM SignoffCommentAttachment WHERE SignoffCommentAttachment.SignoffCommentID IN (SELECT [SignoffCommentID] FROM [SignoffComments] WHERE SignoffID = {0})", signOffID);
```

Comment: It is too bad the MSDN documentation does not point this out. Although {0} is standard syntax for string.Format() commands, it is not remotely like a SQL parameter. I don't think I would ever have guessed this. Thanks!